# Add Tags to files (videos mostly)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, tags, file-storage

I wanted some guidance here:
My program screen records videos then I want to store them with tags so like stackoverflow for example I can find specific categories.

I been thinking of making xml files where I would store the path to the video and tags and whatever other attributes I would need.

What I'm wondering is there another way I should go at this? I want really the user to be independent of my program when he's trying to find a video with a tag.

So really a push in the back to the right direction, otherwise I'll continue with the xml idea ...

Ps: This is all done in C# wpf if it is a need to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standardised format for video, unlike ID3 for .mp3 files.  This means that however you choose to do it the user will need your program to read the tags.

Easier than an .XML file would be just to add the tags directly to the end of the video file, just like ID3 does.

Comment: sounds interesting, you do not happen to know a link which explains how it works ? like how they add tags at the end of the mp3 ?

Comment: The ID3 v1 format was simply to add 128 bytes to the end of the file, with the title, artist, etc.  v2 was much more complicated and could be any size.  For a quick example, check the 5th post here:[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ee65171a-a4e5-4d9a-b2be-337c8f2adeac/)